# can not use xml file in default handler class of sax parser

Tags: android

here is my code .i am trying to use sax parser  but can not find the way to pass the pass of xml file in parse method and getassets() method is not accessible in my class. what should i do to use xml file in my class.

```
   package com.example.com.vyaap.myfirstapp;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private ArrayList<TextView> theviews;
    // string to track each entry.
    private String currTitle="";
    private String currStory="";
    //flag to track of xml processing 
    private Boolean isTitle=false;
    private Boolean isStory= false;
    //Context for user interface
    private Context thecontext;


    public DataHandler(Context cont){
        super();
        theviews = new ArrayList <TextView>();
        thecontext = cont;

    }

    public void startDocument(){
        Log.i("DataHandler","start of xml document");

    }
    public void endDocument(){
        Log.i("DataHandler","end of xml document");
    }
    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts){
    //handle the start element .
        if(qName.equals("author")){
            isTitle=false;
            isStory=false;
            TextView authorview = new TextView(thecontext);

            authorview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(73,136,83));
            String viewText= "Items from "+atts.getValue("name");
            authorview.setText(viewText);
            theviews.add(authorview);

        }
        else if(qName.equals("title")){
            isTitle=true;
            isStory=false;
            TextView titleview= new TextView(thecontext);
            titleview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(100,10,150));

        }
    }
    public void endElement (String uri, String name, String qName)
    {
        if(qName.equals("author")){
            TextView titleview = new TextView(thecontext);
            titleview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(192,140,180));
            titleview.setText(currTitle);
            theviews.add(titleview);
        }
        //handle the end of an element
    }

    public void characters(char ch[],int start, int length ){

        String currText="";
        for(int i=start;i<start+length;i++){
        switch(ch[i]){
        case '\\':
        break;
        case'"':
        break;
        case'\n':
        break;
        case'\t':
        break;
        default: 
        currText+=ch[i];
        break;
        }

        }
        if(isTitle && currText.length()> 0){
        currStory+=currText+"\n";
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<TextView> getData(){

        try{
        System.setProperty("org.xml.driver","org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
        SAXParserFactory parserfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser xmlparser= parserfactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlin= xmlparser.getXMLReader();
        xmlin.setContentHandler(this);
        //InputStream inputstream = getAssets.

                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("music.xml");
                // i got error of create method getassests();
    }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
InputStream inputStream = thecontext.getAssets().open("music.xml");
```

Comment: i tried your code but it  could not find xml file  and its  located in resource/raw folder

Comment: use this InputStream inputStream = thecontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);